# C# how to use the return value in another script

Tags: c#

Thank you. suppose I have two scripts.

I get a return value from a method in one script.

```
public class ClassA {
    public int A (int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

and I want to use the returned value (int A) in another script:

```
class ClassB {

    public ClassA _ClassA = new ClassA();
    public int TheReturn;

    public void update()
    {
        TheReturn = _ClassA.A;
    }
}
```

That's how I tried it. And it is not working..

Thank you guys so much for pointing out the lack of argument in TheReturn = _ClassA.A;

If the Input for A is a reading value (a constantly changing value. eg SerialPort.Reading(), instead of int a, int b). And I want to use the actual "return" value from method A of ClassA. What should I do?

Can I use something like print() and then use Read() in another class?

Comment: You need to _call_ the method, by passing arguments to it. E.g. `TheReturn = _ClassA.A(10, 20);`. Stack Overflow is not the place for getting basic training in how programming languages work. Please take some time, find some good books, and read the language documentation.

Answer (score 0):

your question is really messi, but maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
class ClassB 
{

    public ClassA _ClassA = new ClassA();
    public int TheReturn;

    public void update(int x, int y)
    {
        TheReturn = _ClassA.A(x,y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to use the returned value from ClassA in ClassB. How should I write the code?   sorry for the messy, its my first time asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Do not think in terms of scripts. For C# it does not matter whether the code is in one file or split among 100 files. This is only an organizational concern.

You have two classes.

`ClassA` declares a method `A` with two input parameters and one return value.

If you want to use this method, you first need to create to `ClassA` object. You are doing so. So far so good.

Then you must call this method and pass the required arguments.

```
ClassA aObject = new ClassA();
int result;

result = aObject.A(2, 7);
```

You do so by placing a pair of parentheses after the method name and around the argument list. In this example, the value returned by the method `A` is stored in the variable `result`. You could now print it like this

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

You can also use the result directly instead

```
Console.WriteLine(aObject.A(2, 7));
```

in fact, the method call can be part of an expression like

```
Console.WriteLine(aObject.A(2, 7) * aObject.A(3, 9) + 10);
```

See: [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually want to use the return value from the method in ClassA. Is it possible?

Comment: The result value is not stored in `ClassA`. The method `A` returns this value to the caller. In my example it is stored in the variable `int result`.